# How To: Make array from values of multiple input boxes - then store in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, model

I'm trying to learn how to get the values from all the input boxes below, keep them relative to the 'Product' and store them my model database.

The user can create as many of these "Products" as they want, the three(3) below is an example. They fill out Quantity on one input, paste Link to Product into a input, and put a short Description of Product into another input box.

When the user submits the form, Can I use Javascript or jQuery to get contents of all Products input boxes (Quantity, Link, Description) then create X number of Product arrays to store in my database?

Full explanation: A user is saving Product information to a "Ordering" ticket system. I need to save all the values of each Product to my Ticket model that will save all the other user info, but I'm not sure he best way to do it. Do I create a Product model/database, then store all Product entries into the Product model, then use a key to associate my Product model to my Ticket model? If I do it this way, how can I make it so that multiple tickets can use the same product if it exists already to help eliminate dups. Does that require changing the key?

Or, should I add a column in my Ticket model and store the array of information for the Products in that column?

**View (HTML)**

```
<label> Product 0 </label>
<table>    
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_quantity]0" type="number" value="1">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_link]0" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_descript]0" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<label> Product 1 </label>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_quantity]1" type="number" value="1">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_link]1" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_descript]1" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

<label> Product 2 </label>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_quantity]2" type="number" value="1">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_link]2" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input name="ticket[prod_descript]2" type="text">
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to store this data in my `Tickets` model under one column (if possible) named "orders".

My biggest problem is I don't know how to make an array of each group of "products", in order to store the array into my Model.

I would need to be able to list all the data.
In example:

```
1 http://exampleurl.com/example_producturl Example product description.
5 http://exampleurl.com/example_producturl Another example product description.
```

Please ask if this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it?
You want to make list of data?

```
 1 http://exampleurl.com/example_producturl Example product description.
 5 http://exampleurl.com/example_producturl Another example product description.
```

You can do

```
  <% products.each do |product| %>
    <%=link_to product_path(product)%>
```

and description will be

```
 <%=product.name%>
 <%=product.price%> 
 etc.
```

Or I didn't understand the question?

Comment: So the tricky part is users can dynamically add a new "product". So the amount of products listed to store when the user submits the form is random.  How can I use jQuery or javascript to collect the data of each product, no matter how many product the user had added, and then store each array in my Ticket model under 'orders' column. OR is there a better way to save this data?

Comment: But you can put different (random, or maybe with :where) amount of items in products variable.

Comment: Hmm. I'll play around with this and see if I can get that idea to work then. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Okay - after reading into what you're saying a bit more, this isn't what I'm looking for.